# dynamically use radio buttons in asp.net applications

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developping an asp.net application.

When a user clicks on a page, some radio buttons are added to the the page dynamically.

Then when he clicks on another "update" button, I would liek to check, which of the radio buttons are checked and post back them to the server.

The problem is the following:

I add dynamically the radio buttons in the page_load method.

But when I am on the update button onclick method, I cannot use them to check if they are checked ot not.

I have tried several methods like using a static dictionary of radiobuttons, but I cannot keep a reference on them, when I am on my update method.

This is my method when the page is loading:

```
private static Dictionary<string,RadioButton> buttons;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        RadioButton r = new RadioButton();
        r.Text = i.ToString();
        r.ID = i.ToString();;
        Panel1.Controls.Add(r);
        buttons.Add(i.ToString(), r);
    }
}
```

And this is my method when the user click on the update button where I would like to access to each of my radiobutton depending their id or their text, but I cannot :
For example, If I want all the buttons from 1 to 3 to be checked :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i=1;i<4;i++)
    {
        buttons[i].checked=true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use static dictionary, as web application is meant to be used for multiple users same time. If you want to get your buttons back after postback, you need to loop through control collection of your panel Panel1.Controls.

Comment: ok but with this I am only getting a control element, I have no access to "checked" property. Also, which method do I have to enclosed in a (!if postback), page_load or also the button1_click?

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net will clear your dynamically added controls on every postback. if you want to get their selection you have to do that on client click of button in JS. 
C# Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                RadioButton r = new RadioButton();
                r.Text = i.ToString();
                r.ID = i.ToString();
                r.ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.Static;
                Panel1.Controls.Add(r);

            }
        }
    }
```

and JS Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getCheckedRadios() {
        alert(document.getElementById('1').checked);
    }
</script>
```

aspx code for your button will be:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="getCheckedRadios(); return false;"/>
```

I hope it will help.